# Format date results of postgresql query to 'yyyymmdd'

Tags: postgresql

I have this code in my postgresql
dim_study.created_datetime AS StudyDate,

I need to query results to format to be yyyymmdd.

What is the code I should and use and where should the code be included?  Before that line, within that line or after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_char` to format a timestamp. Pass it the timestamp to be formatted, and the format you want.

```
to_char(dim_study.created_datetime, 'YYYYMMDD') AS StudyDate
```

See [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) for details.